# Why can't I set list pointer to minimal value (sorting words) in the list?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

After inserting new element to the circular doubly linked list, when I set list pointer to minimal value, I can't see the value which was inserted to the list first (by creating the list), I can see only strange characters. 
if I don't set the pointer to minimal value everything is working correctly, but I care to have the pointer set to minimal value.

```
struct Person {
    char surname[N];
};

struct c_dll {
    struct Person *data;
    struct c_dll *next, *prev;
};

struct c_dll *create_list(char *surname) {
    struct Person *new_person = (struct Person *)malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    strcpy(new_person->surname, surname);
    struct c_dll *new_node = (struct c_dll *)malloc(sizeof(struct c_dll));
    if (new_node != NULL) {
        new_node->data = new_person;
        new_node->next = new_node->prev = new_node;
    }
    return new_node;
};

struct c_dll *find_min(struct c_dll *node) {
    char min_surname[20];
    struct c_dll *result, *start;
    strcpy(min_surname, node->data->surname);
    start = result = node;
    do {
        if (strcmp(min_surname, node->data->surname) > 0) {
            strcpy(min_surname, node->data->surname);
            result = node;
        }
        node = node->next;
    } while (start != node);
    return result;
}

struct c_dll *find_next_node(struct c_dll *node, char *surname) {
    node = find_min(node);
    struct c_dll *start = node;
    do {
        if (strcmp(node->data->surname, surname) > 0)
            break;
        node = node->next;
    } while (start != node);
    return node;
}

void add_element(struct c_dll **list_ptr, char *surname) {
    struct Person *new_person = (struct Person *)malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    strcpy(new_person->surname, surname);
    struct c_dll *new_node = (struct c_dll *)malloc(sizeof(struct c_dll));
    if (new_node != NULL) {
        struct c_dll *node;
        new_node->data = new_person;
        node = find_next_node(&(*list_ptr), surname);
        new_node->next = node;
        new_node->prev = node->prev;
        node->prev->next = new_node;
        node->prev = new_node;
    }
    (*list_ptr) = find_min(&(*list_ptr));
}
```

Comment: Both `find_min` and `find_next_node` take a `(struct c_dll *)`, but you pass a `(struct c_dll **)` in a rather convoluted way. Pass `*list_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug is in `add_element`: you pass `&(*list_ptr)` to `find_min` and `find_next_node`, which is incorrect and even a type mismatch that the compiler should diagnose.

You should just pass `*list_ptr` instead.

Here is a modified version:

```c
int add_element(struct c_dll **list_ptr, const char *surname) {
    struct Person *new_person = malloc(sizeof(*new_person));
    if (new_person == NULL)
        return -1;
    strcpy(new_person->surname, surname);
    struct c_dll *new_node = malloc(sizeof(*new_node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        free(new_person);
        return -1;
    } else {
        struct c_dll *node;
        new_node->data = new_person;
        node = find_next_node(*list_ptr, surname);
        new_node->next = node;
        new_node->prev = node->prev;
        node->prev->next = new_node;
        node->prev = new_node;
        *list_ptr = find_min(*list_ptr);
        return 0;
    }
}
```